# vue.js component inline style concatenation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm stuck with a vue.js component inline style concatenation.
My code is the following:

```
components: {
  'twitter-item': {
    props: ['procolors'],
    template: '\
      <div class="color-quadrat" v-bind:data-id="procolors.id" v-bind:style="background-color: #{procolors.user.profile_background_color}">\
      <p>{{procolors.user.profile_background_color}}</p>\
      </div>\
     '
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get `procolors.user.profile_background_color` as inline background color. Special is that the value from `procolors.user.profile_background_color` has no `#`. So I have to add this in the template.

I tried all kinds of recommendations from the web, but none worked for me.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Not exactly sure who downvoted you, or why, but this question is valid. Nuance between the syntax template for variables in attributes vs. non-attributes can be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices in how to add styling. If you use `v-bind:style="..."`, or it shorthand `:style="..."`, you need to pass either a valid string, valid variable or a valid object.

Currently you are trying to parse `background-color: #{procolors.user.profile_background_color}` as javascript, which is not going to work.

You can use a javascript template to create a string:

```
components: {
  'twitter-item': {
    props: ['procolors'],
    template: '\
      <div class="color-quadrat" v-bind:data-id="procolors.id" v-bind:style="`background-color: #${procolors.user.profile_background_color}`">\
      <p>{{procolors.user.profile_background_color}}</p>\
      </div>\
     '
  }
}
```

It is often more readable to refactor it to use a variable or function instead:

```
components: {
  'twitter-item': {
    props: ['procolors'],
    template: '\
      <div class="color-quadrat" v-bind:data-id="procolors.id" v-bind:style="rowColor">\
      <p>{{procolors.user.profile_background_color}}</p>\
      </div>\
     ',
    computed: {
      rowColor () {
        return {
          "background-color": `#${this.procolors.user.profile_background_color}`
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this, which utilizes vue's [style object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1):

```
:style="{backgroundColor: '#' + procolors.user.profile_background_color}"
```

Comment: This is better than my answer. +1.

Comment: @Max what version of vue are you using?

Comment: the latest one running in development mode

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to [Binding inline styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) documentation there are to ways to pass inline styles - as an object or as an array.

In your example, `background-color: #{procolors.user.profile_background_color}` is neither object or an array.

For sake of readability and maintainability (and good practice in general), I'd suggest to create a computed property that will return an object with inline styles. This way it will more clear where is the issue with concatenation:

Template will look as follows:

```
 <div 
     class="color-quadrat" 
     :data-id="procolors.id"
     :style="itemStyles">

     <p>{{ procolors.user.profile_background_color }}</p>
  </div>
```

And computed property should be added to the same component:

```
props: ['procolors'],
template: `...`,
computed: {
  itemStyles () {
    return {
      backgroundColor: `#${this.procolors.user.profile_background_color}`
    }
  }
}
```

If you still prefer to keep it inline, then style binding should be changed to following:

```
v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: `#${procolors.user.profile_background_color}` }"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use style binding with vue3. This is the solution:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from 'vue'
const color = ref("red")
</script>

<template>
  <div class="parti-color" 
       :style="{backgroundColor: color, width: '20px', height: '30px'}"
  />
</template>
```